# How to extract a subimage from a 1-dimension array?

Tags: c++, c, image

I have an image represented by a 1-dimension array (`char[]`). Image height is `H`, image width is `W`, and I would like to extract a subimage starting in `(dx,dy)` and which dimensions are `(dW,dH)`

This seems not to work :

```
subimage(i,j) = image[(j+dy*W) * (W+i+dx)]
```

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula for a particular pixel in an image stored a 1-dimensional array with the stride equal to the image width is:

```
pixel(x,y) = image[(y * width) + x]
```

So the formula you're looking for is (in pseudo-code):

```
subimage(i,j) = image[((j+dy)*W) + (i+dx)]
```

Iterate `j` over `0` to `dH` and `i` over `0` to `dW`.